# Thunderbird: Sync Virtual Folders

Tags: sync, thunderbird

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sync Thunderbird across two computers?](https://superuser.com/questions/328091/how-do-i-sync-thunderbird-across-two-computers)

I use Thunderbird on various computers all on the same imap-account, so all computers share the same mails. Is it somehow possible to synchronize the search-folders/virtual folders I create in Thunderbird between several installations? I'm searching for something similar than [Firefox Sync](http://www.mozilla.com/en-GB/firefox/sync/) for Thunderbird which syncs at least my search folders.
Somebody knows a trick?